# While loading async values for celleditorParams values for agSelectCellEditor in ag-grid, getting values as undefined

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Below is my code for one header field:

```
    {
          headerName: 'Keyword Action',
          editable: true,
          field: 'action',
          cellRenderer: function(params) { return params.value; },
          cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
          filter: 'text',
          cellClass: 'grid-align',
          cellEditorParams:  (params) => {
            let selectedScreenInGrid = params.data.screenName;
            return {
                values: this.screenToActionMap(selectedScreenInGrid,function(res){
                  return res;
                })
            };
          }
        },
```

and below is my function where I am fetching async values to display in Action field.

```
    screenToActionMap(screenName,callback) {
     let scenarioGeneratorComp = this;
      scenarioGeneratorComp.scenarioService.getActions(screenName)
      .subscribe((res:any) => {
        console.log('Actions response ' + res);
        res.forEach(function(elm:any,idx:number){
          scenarioGeneratorComp.actionsForGrid.push(elm.actionName);
        });
        return callback([scenarioGeneratorComp.actionsForGrid]);
      });
    }
```

Here before I could fetch the data, the celleditorparams is taking values as undefined. I am using callback function here to wait untill my actionsForGrid values required for celleditorparams in the grid.
    Could any one please help me out with this in displaying the values fetched from my asynchronous call.